# Redshift CheckMaxRowError Error with no errors in sys_load_error_detail

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have this running in Python Lambda

```
create_temp_table = f"CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_{table_name} (LIKE xxxx.public.{table_name});"

BEGIN;

COPY temp_{table_name}
FROM 's3://{bucket}/{key}'
IAM_ROLE 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx1:role/AmazonRedshiftS3Lambdaxxxx'
CSV IGNOREHEADER 1 DELIMITER ','
COMPUPDATE OFF
EMPTYASNULL
BLANKSASNULL
DATEFORMAT 'auto'
TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
IGNOREBLANKLINES
MAXERROR 5
REGION AS '{region}';

CALL {proc_name}();

COMMIT;
```

and I end up with the following error.
The CSV is aboutn 831k rows.

> {'S': 'ERROR', 'C': 'XX000', 'M': "Load into table 'temp_xxxxx_data' failed.  Check 'sys_load_error_detail' system table for details.", 'F': '../src/pg/src/backend/commands/commands_copy.c', 'L': '724', 'R': 'CheckMaxRowError'}

when I query `sys_load_error_detail` it is empty.

How can I find out what the actual issue is? There is only 1 result in google for `CheckMaxRowError` which uses a view to get the error, but the STL and STV tables are not exposed, maybe they were back then.

Comment: Check STL_LOAD_ERRORS.

Comment: STL_* are not available
ERROR: permission denied for relation stl_load_errors

Comment: So it looks like you don't have permissions to access the log files to see the nature of the failing rows.

Comment: stl* are not available.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/sys_view_migration.html

Comment: Ok important detail - you are on Redshift serverless.  Still likely a permissions issues as the SYS views only allow access to the user's rows in the underlying tables.  Are you accessing as the same user that is performing the COPY?  Your COPY is run by python but I suspect your SELECT on SYS views is in a bench.  You can see if a superuser can view the details of the COPY as they won't be user limited.

Comment: Yes, I think it's finally sorted. Thanks!